# Rails - add data to relation's relation table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, paperclip

i have `questions` , `answers` and `photos` `models`. I use `paperclip` for images.

I can't add `answer's image` to `photos table` using below code.

```
 q = Question.new(
            title:  p[:title],
            post:  p[:post]
            )

p[:answers].each do |a|
  q.answers.build(body: a[:body])
  if a[:images]
    a[:images].each do |e|
      q.answers.photos.create(image: e) #this line gives the error
    end
  end
end
```

Error line `q.answers.photos.create(image: e)`

Error is :

```
undefined method `photos' for #<Answer::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x00007f9592208800>
```

I created associations for my models like :

```
class Answer < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :question
 has_many :photos
end

class Photo < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :answer

  has_attached_file :image,
                    :path => ":rails_root/public/img/:filename", validate_media_type: false

  do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :image
end
```

Comment: Try `create` method instead of `build`

Comment: The error is due to the `create` method, not the `build` method.

Comment: Why are you doing `p[:answer]` (for example) instead of `p.answer`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A photo belongs to one question and one answer. But you try to create a photo that belongs to several `q.answers`.

You probably want to do something like this:

```
question = Question.new(title: p[:title], post: p[:post])

p[:answers].each do |a|
  answer = q.answers.create(body: a[:body])
  if a[:images]
    a[:images].each do |e|
      answer.photos.create(image: e, question: q)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, since `answer` isn't saved, will `answer.photos.create` work ok?

Comment: @jvillian Good question. Actually I am not sure. Looking at the Rails Guides for `has_many` doesn't give an answer. It is probably better to create the answer first. Even if it was not necessary you would get better error messages when a validation fails.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but now I'm getting a  `rollback transaction ` for images. Am I missing something? I don't use any validation   `do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :image`

Comment: I think the reason is associations. But I couldn't solve it.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, it's not ruby-ish to do `p[:title]`, `a[:image]`, etc. (Also, you're typing three extra characters per method call and, you know, life is short.) Just do `p.title`, `a.image`, etc. So, your code should look like:

```
q = Question.new(title: p.title, post: p.post)

p.answers.each do |answer|
  q.answers.build(body: answer.body)
  if answer.images
    answer.images.each do |image|
      q.answers.photos.create(image: image)
    end
  end
end
```

Now, you want to create new photos for the `answer` you instantiated here:

```
q.answers.build(body: answer.body)
```

Instead, you're trying to call `photos` on the enumerable that is returned by `q.answers.photos`. And, naturally, that enumerable (an `ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy` in this case) doesn't have that method. So, you're getting the `undefined method` error.

You could try:

```
q = Question.new(title: p.title, post: p.post)

p.answers.each do |answer|
  new_answer = q.answers.build(body: answer.body)
  if answer.images
    answer.images.each do |image|
      new_answer.photos.create(image: image)
    end
  end
end
```

Except you haven't saved `new_answer` yet, so it doesn't have an `id`. In which case, it *may* still error out.

So, perhaps:

```
q = Question.new(title: p.title, post: p.post)

p.answers.each do |answer|
  new_answer = q.answers.create(body: answer.body)
  if answer.images
    answer.images.each do |image|
      new_answer.photos.create(image: image)
    end
  end
end
```

I'm not sure if you *really* want all those duplicate `Photo`s (maybe you do). But, if you don't, I think I would do something like:

```
class AnswerPhoto < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :answer
  belongs_to :photo
end

class Answer < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :question
  has_many :answer_photos
  has_many :photos, through: :answer_photos
end

class Photo < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :question
  has_many :answer_photos
  has_many :answers, through: :answer_photos
end
```

In which case you might do something like:

```
q = Question.new(title: p.title, post: p.post)

p.answers.each do |answer|
  new_answer = q.answers.create(body: answer.body)
  new_answer.photos << answer.photos
end
```

It looks to me you have some `N+1` querying going on there, so you'll want to look into `.include`. And, since you're not really using `answer.photos` as proper ruby objects (you only really want those `id`s), you might look into `.pluck`.